# Drop dialog on a list page not disappearing automatically

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r2, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

When I add a drop-dialog to a list page, the drop dialog drops down when I click on it, but does not disappear when I click somewhere else.

I am trying to add my own drop-dialog, but I can reproduce this issue with standard Dynamics AX objects. I guess I am just missing some property on an object, but I just cannot figure out which one.

If you want to reproduce my problem in order to solve it, do the following:

1. Create a new Form. (Form 1)
2. Change the FormTemplate property  to ListPage (Click on Yes)
3. Add the query MainAccountListPage to the DataSources
4. Create an ActionPanTab.
5. Add a Drop-dialog button with the menu item MainAccountListPageBalanceParameters.
6. Save and open the new List page by right clicking and choosing open. (or open the menu item)

*In my case, when I click on Parameters, the drop dialog drops down. When I then click outside the drop-dialog, it disappears as it should.*

[image]

7. Create a new display menu item. Set the object to the new list page (Form 1)
8. Drag the Menu item to any menu. I added mine to General ledger (Common)
   [image]
9. Restore, open new workspace. Click on the new menu item in the general ledger menu.

[image]

10. Click on “parameters” and click outside the drop dialog.

When I do this the drop dialog does not disappear again. You can see this same drop dialog working fine on the Main Accounts list page. I have tried changing properties on both menu items, on the menu, on the form etc. I have tried different drop dialogs and different list pages. It always works on the details page and when opened from the AOT.

Am I missing a property? Is the entire way I am adding the drop dialog wrong?

Comment: I was able to reproduce this strange behavior, but I couldn't find a reason for it. I do not think you are doing something wrong when adding the drop dialog. A possible solution could be to start with a duplicate of form `MainAccountListPage` and delete all the stuff you do not need in this form. While deleting, check regularly if the drop dialog still works as expected. Kinda roundabout, but either you end up with a form and a working drop dialog or you know that the drop dialog stops working when you delete element x.

Comment: @FH-Inway - Thank you for taking the time to reproduce the issue. Knowing that this issue is also on other installations at least tells me the issue is not related to our installation, setup or code. I have tried doing the opposite. I made a new List Page and added properties to make it exactly the same as the EcoResProductPerCompanyListPage (which has the DimensionGroups drop dialog). I am going to try your suggestion and see if I can learn anything new.

Comment: I thought I was the only one. I can second that I've had unexplained strangeness with drop dialog. Try hitting the dialog multiple times in a row and I think it will open several instances of it.

Comment: That's right! It opens more instances with blue windows lines and an exit cross at the top... at least you can then click on the cross to close the duplicate instances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to the above example is.. add the *MainAccountDetailPart* Form part to the list page's (Form1) Parts.

With my other example, EcoResProductPerCompanyListPage, I had to add the EcoResProductVariantsPerCompanyFactBox to Parts.

I have no idea why this is, but adding a part to a list page fixes the drop dialogs. For example, adding *MainAccountDetailPart* Form part to a new list page not only fixes the MainAccountListPageBalanceParameters in my example, but it also fixes any other drop dialog that previously did not want to close. Removing the part the breaks **all** the drop dialogs in the list page again.

Thanks, FH-Inway, for the suggestion, I would have never have found the answer without your method. The solution really surprised me!